# How to add /pool to my sources.list file in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, package, pool

I have created a mirror of the Princeton ubuntu package repository on an external hard drive. In the mirror I have included the /dists and /pool directories. How do I add /pool to my sources.list file so I can use apt to install packages from /pool?

Answer (score -1):

Give the path till you see folders dists and path on sources.list . Put a space . Give the folder name from dists you want to add. Put a space.
Give the names of folder inside pools you want to add multi etc.
Repeat for the dists folders you want in your sources.list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).